# Xcode : Count elements in string array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there any quick way I can get the number of strings within a NSString array?

```
NSString *s[2]={@"1", @"2"}
```

I want to retrieve the length of **2** from this. I there something like (s.size) 
I know there is the -length method but that is for a string not a string array.
I am new to Xcode please be gentle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

```
NSArray *stringArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSLog(@"count = %d", [stringArray count]);
```

Comment: Yes i will be using a mutable array in the end. But just out of curiosity. Is there really no way you can retrieve this length?

Comment: Actually, you should use `[stringArray count]` since it's an instance method and not a property.

Comment: @Rengers That does not make any difference. A readonly property is exactly the same as an instance method.

Comment: @Rengers, count - is a getter. It can be used as a property

Comment: I know it doesn't make any difference. It's just that it's a wrong habit to call methods using the property notation ;).

Comment: Yes, a getter and setter. Anyway, it's still bad practice to call an instance method as if it were defined as a property IMHO.

Comment: @Rengers, dot notation has nothing to do with a property. It is an alternative way to call methods. Yes, it was created because of properties but regardless to your opinion it's not a bad practice to use it for methods which were not synthesized from a property. In most cases you would have to search the class headers to learn how the method is declared.

Comment: I know it is just syntactic sugar. But what if I create a method called `login` that does a bunch of stuff, communicates with the server and flips a view when done. It is bad practice to call that using `foo.login`? It works right? IMHO, as long as the docs state it as an instance method, you should call it as an instance method. But hey, different people, different styles :).

Comment: If I suppose that `login` has signature `-(id)login` which would be pretty strange for such method, its name suggests that it's not a getter and then the dot notation should not be used. Would you call it with dot notation if somebody adds `@property (nonatomic, readonly) id login` to the class?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way. Note that this works only if the array is not created dynamically using `malloc`.

```
NSString *array[2] = {@"1", @"2"}

//size of the memory needed for the array divided by the size of one element.
NSUInteger numElements = (NSUInteger) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(NSString*));
```

This type of array is typical for C, and since Obj-C is C's superset, it's legal to use it. You only have to be extra cautious.

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(s)/sizeof([NSString string]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to search for _countf in objective-c but it seems not existing, so assuming that sizeof and typeof operators works properly and you pass valid c array, then the following may work.

```
#define _countof( _obj_ ) ( sizeof(_obj_) / (sizeof( typeof( _obj_[0] ))) )

NSString *s[2]={@"1", @"2"} ;
NSInteger iCount = _countof( s ) ;
```